# Как сделать, чтоб переменная была видна внутри html()?

Tags: jquery

Например

```
var variable = "plus";

$('#id').click(function(){
    $(this).html('текст'+variable+'текст');
})
```

Comment: что Вы имеете в виду под словами "была видна внутри `html()`"?

Comment: Чтобы работал код и всё. Должно заменить содержимое блока на "текстplusтекст". А как я написал, так не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была такая беда. Решил проблему конкатенацией в переменную до вставки в $.html()

Comment: Знаю, что способ кривой, но работало

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема?
Не смотря на то, что onclick - событие, и оно отработает позже внешнего кода, переменная `variable` будет доступна внутри обработчика.

Эта полезная особенность JavaScript называется -  [замыканием](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/38642/).

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен что смог разгадать ваш злой и гениальный замысел, но мне кажется что в вашем случае можно было бы выкрутиться используя функцию live которая успешно привязывает обработчик ко всем вновь созданным элементам.